# Twig cache permissions

Tags: wordpress, twig, vagrant

I just worked with Windows 7 before and now I'm working with MAC OS. I cloned my project (it works with Twig and wordpress and I'm using a virtual machine via vagrant) and everything should work but when I enter the website it gives me the following message:

```
    Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 
    'Unable to create the cache directory (/vagrant/myProject/cache/c2/94).'
    in /vagrant/myProject/wp-content/.../libraries/Twig/Environment.php:1199
```

I guess it is some kind of problem about permissions but I don't know how to fix it exactly. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you created a `/vagrant` directory, I think default permissions are root.

You can try:

```
sudo mkdir /vagrant/myProject/cache
sudo chown -R $USER:staff /vagrant
```

And then try again (assuming your current user runs the apache server).

If this does not work, please do:

```
ls -l /vagrant
```

and:

```
ls -l /vagrant/myProject/cache/
```

And try to set permissions so the cache permissions are the same.